# How to set JsTimeline language to current DNN language

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, 2sxc

To set the language for JS Timeline one must add this line inside the createStoryJS in the apps scripts.js :

```
lang: "de"
```

How would you go about having this set automatically to the current DNN Language?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be to have some server side code like

Pseodo code:

```
<script>
  var langPage = "@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture";
</script>
```

now you have the languge in your JS, and can re-use it.